# Why would sending email from a django listener cause a broken pipe when invoked by ajax?

Tags: python, ajax, django, email, satchmo

I have a django listener that sends an email. It works perfectly under normal circumstances, but when it is triggered by AJAX, I see this error on the console:

```
[Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I am using ***python manage.py runserver*** to test it, hence the error on the console.

My suspicion is that because it only happens when the AJAX ***POST*** occurs, it must be something to do with the AJAX socket closing before the email has had time to be completely sent, and when it finally is eventually sent, there is nowhere for the response to go. Does this sound feasible? The error is reported by `/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py` in the class `_fileobject : flush()` method.

Here's a snippet of the listener setup:

```
signals.satchmo_order_status_changed.connect(capture_new_order_listener)

def capture_new_order_listener(sender, oldstatus="", newstatus="", order=None, **kwargs):
    email_notify(order, template = 'shop/email/foo.xt', template_html = 'shop/email/foo.html')
```

Then I have this:

```
def email_notify(order, template='', template_html=''):
    ...
    send_store_mail(subject, c, template, [order.contact.email],
                template_html=template_html, format_subject=True,
                sender=order_confirmation_sender)
```

The AJAX python handler looks like so:

```
def ajax_update(request, **kwargs):
    order.add_status('New') # Triggers sending an email
```

The AJAX jquery looks like this:

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").mousedown(function(){
        $.post("{% url ajax_update %}",
        {
            some_var:$("#some_var").val(),
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

How do I get rid of this error? Or should I just ignore it? I'm not sure how it will affect the Apache/WSGI server. It seems I can't catch the exception at send_store_mail()

***Edit 1:***

Here's the full text of the exception:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 36564)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 283, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 309, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 322, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 562, in __init__
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 618, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 661, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 304, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the *full* traceback of the error?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - see Edit 1.

Comment: The client disconnected before the full data was written back to the socket. Usually this is harmless.

Comment: Broken pipes usually happen very often on django's development server when spamming many requests/s.This is due to the server being single threaded. Don't know if this is the case for you, but as Martin Pieters said, this is usually harmless. Safest thing to do would probably be to see what happens on an apache/WSGI server (should only take you a couple of minutes to set that up ...)